# Why does this Oracle regexp_like test FALSE?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Why does this Oracle `regexp_like` expression test FALSE?
I'm running this PLSQL on Oracle 11g.

**v_string** is a 0 and two spaces. It tests TRUE at *REGEX101*

[image: Oracle regexp_like]

```
 declare  v_string varchar2(30) := '0  ';

 begin    
 dbms_output.put_line('Length is ' || length(v_string) );   

 if  regexp_like(v_string,'^[0-9A-Z\s]{1,3}$') then   
      dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');    
 else    
      dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');    
 end if;   

 end;
```

Comment: Just FYI: your regex in Oracle does not match a whitespace. But it will match `0s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use a shorthand character class inside a bracket expression since it is treated as 2 separate characters, `\` and `s`. Use an equivalent `[:space:]` POSIX character class:

```
^[0-9A-Z[:space:]]{1,3}$
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that

| [Shorthand character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) and other common PCRE-like variations | Oracle POSIX version |
| --- | --- |
| `\d` | `[:digit:]` (any digit) |
| `\s` | `[:space:]` (all) / `[:blank:]` (horizontal only) |
| `\w` | `[:alnum:]_` (`\w` matches letters, digits and underscores in most flavors) |
| `[\p{P}\p{S}]` | `[:punct:]` (any punctuation and math symbols) |
| `\p{L}` | `[:alpha:]` (any letter) |
| `\p{Cc}` | `[:cntrl:]` (control characters) |
| `[\d\p{L}\p{P}\p{S}]` | `[:graph:]` (any punctuation, letter and digit symbols) |
| `\p{Ll}` | `[:lower:]` (lowercase letters) |
| `\p{Lu}` | `[:upper:]` (uppercase letters) |
| `[a-fA-F0-9]` | `[:xdigit:]` (hexadecimal number digits) |

**NOTE**: When using POSIX character classes, ALWAYS use them inside bracket expressions:

Cf. <s>`KEYWORD_([:alnum:]+)`</s> and **`KEYWORD_([[:alnum:]]+)`** (or - to fully emulate `\w` - `KEYWORD_([[:alnum:]_]+)`, with the underscore).

Comment: Thanks,You steered me in the right direction:https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm#i690819